# SMS Firebase Auth Permission Denied

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

For my iOS app, I have users sign in using their phone number via Firebase Auth. It works fine on my device using my real number. When I sign in using a test number I had added (e.g. +1 000-000-0000), I get the following printed error:

> Write at errors/+10000000000 failed: Missing or insufficient
> permissions.

I also noticed this printed message from my AppDelegate didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate function:

> [AnyHashable("com.google.firebase.auth"): {
> warning = "This fake notification should be forwarded to Firebase Auth.";
> }]

To note, I have signed in using these test numbers before successfully so I'm unsure why they all of a sudden fail now. I deleted and re-downloaded the app, I deleted and re-added the google plist file, I deleted and re-added the test number, I checked my permissions which hadn't changed from when the test numbers had signed in successfully prior, I checked my app enabled capabilities, and I checked the Firebase project Apple app configuration.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Gladly can provide more info where needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the SMS region policy...After setting the Firebase SMS region policy to "Deny" and list of regions blank, the test numbers now work.